# Why does this RSA keygen/encryption function return the original message for encryption and a large number for decryption?

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

I am trying to create my own function for RSA encryption, but the results are not what I want.

I have tested the external modules for lcm, gcd, exponents by squaring with exponents, modular multiplicative inverse, and primality test. I was following https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem).

I have created valid primes digest1 and digest2. I checked those to make sure they are prime. They are also very large.

```
n=digest1*digest2
tn=lcm.lcm(digest1-1,digest2-1)
#totient of n
for e in range(start,1000000000000000000000):
    #a large number for coprime to tn
    if math.gcd(e,tn)==1.0:
        d=modularminverse.modInverse(e,tn)
        if len(str(d))<200:
            #for small e
            break
n=int(n)
e=int(e)
d=int(d)
publickey=(n,e)
privatekey=(n,d)
return (publickey, privatekey)
```

I created e and d, and this is the encryption.

```
keys=None
while keys == None:
    keys=rsa()
print(keys)
encryptmessage=fastpower.fast_power(101,keys[0][1],keys[0][0])
print(encryptmessage)
decryptmessage=fastpower.fast_power(encryptmessage,keys[1][1],keys[1][0])
print(decryptmessage)
```

Here, the external function names suggest their usage e.g. fastpower.fast_power is exponentiation with modulus.

I expect the result to be a long number then 101, but with start = 10000000, it gives me something like:

> 101
>   1943008535967955120523586573083029590205252967627388466351631986945832635342057989695130781235934234951139601298113497667511028938689905543444926395107114

which is backwards. With start=10000000000000000 or a sufficiently large number, both encryptmessage and decryptmessage becomes a large number.

Comment: "Compute the Carmichael's totient function of the product as λ(n) = lcm(p − 1, q − 1) giving." If d is too large, the encryption is too expensive.

Comment: My previous comment was wrong. But still it's hard to figure out what your question is. Your output doesn't match your program. And d and e can't both be small at the same time.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Okay, but the filter aside, I want to fix the problem where the output isn't what I want it to be.

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/183330/116272 might help

Comment: It's impossible to reproduce without the missing pieces like `fast_power`, `modInverse`, etc. See [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JamesKPolk Is is viable to say just that I verified they work? I don't want too much code in the question.